# FIle saving path

Tags: java

I have created code that makes print screens and saves them as an imiage, but I don't really know how to change the path of saving the file for other folder in my main project folder. Any ideas?

```
private static void print(JPanel comp, String nazwa) {

    // Create a `BufferedImage` and create the its `Graphics`
    BufferedImage image = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration()
            .createCompatibleImage(comp.getWidth(), comp.getHeight());
    Graphics graphics = image.createGraphics();
    // Print to BufferedImage
    comp.paint(graphics);
    graphics.dispose();
    // Output the `BufferedImage` via `ImageIO`

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(nazwa+".png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the full path in the `File` constructor:

```
new File("/home/cipek/images/filename.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

However I have still got a problem. I am not sure that udnerstand it properly. 
cipek- is my project name
images- folder where i want to keep images
But what about home?? I rewrite "home" however it doesn't work.I don't want to give whole path because I will use this proram on other computers so the path will be diffrent every time.